# Recovery password devise RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, passwords

I have a problem when I change the password on devise gem.

When I click in the forget password link, devise sends me an email with a link to change the password. I click this link and send me to a url like this:

```
local:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=cb42aca8ae55c797facf38464ef4484af33a09890bf731f0392cde785abebddc
```

If I input a bad password in the field (not pass the validation), the gem redirect to the url `local:3000/users/password/` and at this time I enter a good password, but the password is not modified in the DB.

If I enter a good password the first time, all runs fine.

I think that the problem is in the url, because it did not add the edit part and the parameters.

How can I fix this problem?